# Simple Regular Expression in Java

Tags: java, regex, decimal

How can I create a pattern for:

this is the order from beginning to end:

at least 0, at most 3 digits they are from 0-9

a decimal point after (has to be there)

at least 0, at most two digits after they are from 0-9

Thanks!

Don't have to but please explain!

Example inputs:

444.56 
3.44 
33.44 
3.44 
.35 
3. 
3.0 
2.22

Comment: I did something like:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is:

```
^\d{0,3}\.\d{0,2}$
```

You can break it down as:

1. `^` is the start of the line
2. `\d` specifies a digit from 0 to 9. `{0,3}` means 0 to 3 times.
3. `\.` specifies a decimal point, taken literally
4. `\d` specifies a digit from 0 to 9. `{0,2}` means 0 to 2 times.
5. `$` is the end of the line

You'll need to use double backslashes if you make a Java string, however. It would look like:

```
String regex = "^\\d{0,3}\\.\\d{0,2}$"
```

[Regexper](http://www.regexper.com/#%5E%5Cd%7B0%2C3%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B0%2C2%7D%24) gives the explanation as an image

Comment: thank you so much I was on this simple idea but somehow was stuck with simple flaws that take up much time for no reason I really appreciate it.